# how to simplify this binomial expansion

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Is there any way to simplify this term:
$$\sum_{v=1}^m v(1-\frac{1}{v})^u\binom{m}{v}p^v(1-p)^{m-v}$$
The term $(1-\frac{1}{v})^u$ is really annoying.

---

This expansion appear in a specific version of the urn and ball game.
Suppose there are $u$ balls that will be randomly allocated to $V$ urns with $V$ being a random variable with binomial distribution $B(m,p)$.

Then the expected number of urns with at least one ball should be:
$$
\sum_{v=0}^m v(1-(1-\frac{1}{v})^u) \binom{m}{v} p^v (1-p)^{m-v}
$$

Break the expansion into two parts. The first part:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{v=0}^m v\binom{m}{v}p^v(1-p)^{m-v} &= mp \sum_{v=1}^m \binom{m-1}{v-1}p^{v-1}(1-p)^{m-v} \\
 & = mp
\end{align}
$$
My question is how to deal with the second part.

Comment: Are there any conditions on $u$?

Comment: No. See my description of where the expansion comes from

Comment: Well, if you have $u$ balls, I would hope $u$ is a non-negative integer!

Comment: Ok. Sorry for being not rigorous. $u$, $m$ are non-negative integers. $0 \leq p \leq 1$